# PowerShell, search specific directories for specific filename

Tags: search, powershell, directory, copy

I've got a program outputting a filename to the console at the moment.

I want to give it a series of directories to search through (in order) to search through to find that filename and, if it finds it, copy to another directory.

I've got this far:

```
[string]$fileName = "document12**2013" #** for wildcard chars
[bool]$found = false
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Public\Documents" -Recurse | Where-Object { !$PsIsContainer -and GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name) -eq "filename" -and $found = true }

if($found = true){
Copy-Item C:\Users\Public\Documents\ c:\test
}
```

As it stands I've got two issues. I only know how to look through one directory, and I don't know how to specify the script to copy the particular file I've just found.

Answer (score 3):

The Path parameter accepts an array of paths so you can specify more than one. You use the Filter parameter to get the file name you're after and pipe the results to the `Copy-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Public\Documents,$path2,$path3 -Recurse -Filter $fileName | 
Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
```

Comment: This is infinitely easier `dir C:\Users -recurse -filter "filename.txt" -File ` as long as you're okay with only searching one directory at a time

Answer (score 1):

What about wrapping this into a function?

Using Shay's Approach:

```
function copyfile($path,$fileName,$Destination) {
Get-ChildItem -Path  $path -Recurse -Filter $fileName | 
Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
}

$path1=C:\Users\Public\Documents
$path2=C:\Users\Public\Music
$path3=C:\Users\Public\Pictures

copyfile $path1 corporate_policy.docx \\workstation\c$\users\Public\Documents
copyfile $path2 intro_from_ceo.mp3 \\workstation\c$\users\Public\Music
copyfile $path3 corporate_logo.jpg \\workstation\c$\users\Public\Pictures
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this in one pipeline:

```
$folders = 'C:\path\to\folder_A', 'C:\path\to\folder_B', ...

$folders | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter filename.* |
    ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\test\'
```

Note that you **must** have a trailing backslash if you're using a folder as the destination in `Copy-Item`, otherwise the cmdlet will try to replace the folder `C:\test` with a file `C:\test`, which will cause an error.

Comment: You don't need to pipe the paths to `gci`. See @ShayLevy's answer

Comment: We don't know where the paths are coming from, so there may (or may not) be a pipeline in place of `$folders`. With Shay's approach you'd have to assign its results to a variable first, or run it as a subexpression.